# Trying to webscrape a table but cant

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Theres this table i wanna scrape and get all of its details. The html code is this one:

```
<table id="bnConnectionTemplate:r1:0:tl1" class="detailTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Name: </th>
        <td>EVERBRITE CORPORATION LIMITED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><abbr title="Australian Company Number">ACN: </abbr></th>
        <td>104 436 704</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><abbr title="Australian Business Number">ABN: </abbr></th>
        <td><a id="bnConnectionTemplate:r1:0:j_id__ctru57pc2" class="contentLink af_goLink" href="http://abr.business.gov.au/Search.aspx?SearchText=96%20104%20436%20704" target="_blank"><span title="">96 104 436 704</span><span class="hiddenHint"> (External Link)</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Registration date: </th>
        <td>15/04/2003</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Next review date: </th>
        <td>15/04/2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Former name(s): </th>
        <td>VISIONGLOW GLOBAL LIMITED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Status: </th>
        <td>Deregistered</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Date deregistered: </th>
        <td>7/09/2012</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Type: </th>
        <td>Australian Public Company, Limited By Shares</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Locality of registered office: </th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Regulator: </th>
        <td>Australian Securities &amp; Investments Commission</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My problem is that i cant get this table even if i try to get it by its class or id.

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import requests
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get("https://connectonline.asic.gov.au/RegistrySearch/faces/landing/panelSearch.jspx?searchText=104+436+704&searchType=OrgAndBusNm&_adf.ctrl-state=139sjjyk9g_15").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
```

I tried doing:

```
table = soup.find('table', class_= 'detailTable') # Gives output : none

table = soup.find('table', id="bnConnectionTemplate:r1:0:tl1") # Gives output : none
```

At this point i m confused as to why this is happening.I have webscraped in the past with these commands and they worked fine.Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you print out the entire downloaded result, is that table there in your output?

Comment: I tried that link and I don't think its returning anything like detailTable in its content. Content on web always change. Maybe that's what happened.

Comment: If I use the table you provided as source both functions work. As @Gautam points out, the url you scrape doesn't return this table

Comment: Grabbing the URL you mentioned, I get a whole bunch of tables, even with similar IDs, but none with the same ID or class you mention. Maybe they refactored their code at some point and renamed some things?

The `id` looks like it's generated using a CMS or a component-oriented web framework that lets you nest components in one another, so they might have given a meaningful name to whatever `tl1` used to be.

Comment: So the problem is probably on the url ?Ok guys thanks a lot!